# Finding the coefficients of a decomposition of complicated expression into products of special functions

Tags: special-functions, physics, series-expansion, coefficients

I have the following expression which arises while studying minimal models in CFT. The 4-point amplitude of scalars is given by

$$G(z,\overline{z}) = ((1-z)(1-\overline{z}))^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}\mathcal{H}\bigg(\frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{m}{m+1}, \frac{2}{m+1}\bigg) - \\
\frac{\Gamma^2\big(\frac{2}{m+1}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2}{m+1}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2m-1}{m+1}\big)((z-1)(\overline{z}-1))^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}(z\overline{z})^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}}{\Gamma\big(\frac{1}{m+1}\big)\Gamma^2\big(\frac{2m}{m+1}\big)\Gamma\big(\frac{2-m}{m+1}\big)}\mathcal{H}\bigg(\frac{m}{m+1},\frac{2-m}{m+1},\frac{2m}{m+1}\bigg)
$$

edited as $\Gamma^2(x)\to \Gamma[x]^2$ ?

```
 G[z, z\[Conjugate]] = 
((1 - z) (1 - z\[Conjugate]))^((m - 1)/(m + 1)) H[1/(m + 1), 1/(m + 1), 2/( m + 1)] -  
(\[CapitalGamma][2/(m + 1)]^2 \[CapitalGamma][2/(  m + 1)] *
 \[CapitalGamma][(2 m - 1)/(m + 1)])/
(\[CapitalGamma][1/( m + 1)] * \[CapitalGamma][(2 m)/(m + 1)]^2 *
  \[CapitalGamma][( 2 - m)/(m + 1)]) *
    H[m/(m + 1), (2 - m)/(m + 1), (2 m)/(m + 1)]
```

which takes values $m = 3, 4, 5, \cdots$ etc. for various unitary minimal models. The function $\mathcal{H}$ is given by
$$\mathcal{H}(a,b,c) = F(a,b,c,z)F(a,b,c,\overline{z})$$ where $F$ is `Hypergeometric2F1`. I can decompose this $G(z,\overline{z})$ as
$$ G(z, \overline{z}) = (1-z)^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}}(1-\overline{z})^{\frac{m-1}{m+1}} \sum_{\Delta, \ell}c_{\Delta, \ell} g_{\Delta, \ell}(z, \overline{z})$$,
where the functions $g_{\Delta, \ell}$ are given by
$$g_{\Delta, \ell} = \frac{k_{\Delta + \ell}(z)k_{\Delta-\ell}(\overline{z}) + k_{\Delta+\ell}(\overline{z}) k_{\Delta - \ell}(z)}{\delta_{0,\ell} + 1}$$

where in turn the $k$ are defined as
$$k_a(x) = x^{a/2}F(a/2, a/2, a, x)$$

I want to obtain the coefficients $c_{\Delta,\ell}$ for a given $m$. Right now I would be happy if I can obtain it for $m = 4$. I have the coefficients for $m = 3$ but I haven't figured out how to obtain them for $m = 4$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post Mathematica `code` what you have tried?